# how to replace characters in a string with image and show it in a textview

Tags: android

I am building a messaging app in android. I need to show some smiley image when a group of specific character appeared together in a string. Like if **Hello friends :p** shows in textview, i like to replace **:p** with some image like **smile.png** and show this in that textview. How can i show this message with an image in a textview?

Comment: in textview how will you show image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TextWatcher

```
 private TextWatcher myTW = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
};
```

and then you need to append it to your EditText
Note: this is my opinion how it can be solved, maybe there are better solutions